# I can't use JQueryUI with ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use JQueryUI with my MVC4 application but i don't see the effect that i want.
I will show you the code, i think that it's beginner mistake. I must have forget a directive.

**_Layout.cshtml** (Just declaration)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Mon application ASP.NET MVC</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

**myView.cshtml**

```
@section JavaScript
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@{
    if (!Session.IsNewSession && Session.Contents["connecte"].Equals(true))
    {
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
        </div> 
        <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>  
    }
    else
    {
     <div class="group_bannner_right">
        <img src="~/Images/picture.png" width="550" height="316" alt="baner">
    </div>

    <header class="group_bannner_left">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Simple.Think. </h1>
            <h2>
                “The little things are infinitely the most important.“
            </h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header> 
    }   
}
```

I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' 
(index):18 (anonymous function) 
(index):18 fire 
jquery-1.8.2.js:988 self.fireWith 
jquery-1.8.2.js:1096 jQuery.extend.ready 
jquery-1.8.2.js:420 DOMContentLoaded
```

Comment: Looks good to me, Did you build after you edited the Bundler file?, and/or check to see what/if any console errors are.

Comment: I didn't edit the Bundler file.

Comment: I just want to do this
[JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

Comment: Check the javascript console and network tab in your browser's dev tools for errors.

Comment: I have this error in relation with my case :

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' (index):18
(anonymous function) (index):18
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:988
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1096
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:420
DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Thanks Jason I found my mistake when you said me to check the javascript console. I was include twice the JQuery and after it bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI is not being loaded, press CTRL + SHIFT + F, search entire solution for "~/bundles/jqueryui". You will see a find match in BundleConfig.cs, there you will find the file path is not correct for where jQuery resides in your website.

A cause for this would be if you reorganized your jQuery UI files manually.

Edit the file path for jQueryUI in the BundleConfig.cs so it is correct, make sure to build your project after changing BundleConfig.cs.